# Add new element to an array each time the function is called

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, append

this is probably very easy but I'm trying to add the current weather location to an array each time the 'add to favorite' button is clicked. The location changes every time the user is searching for an other one. So each time he's looking for a new location I want the ability to add this to an array so I can after display all fav locations to a specific page. Right now each time the function is called its working but if I do it again with another location it rewrites the first one and the array remains with only 1 element.  Anybody to help ?

Thanks

```
  let arr = [];

  const favCity = () => {
    debugger;
    let newArr = [...arr];
    let favCity = weatherSelector.weatherInfo.location.name;
    newArr.push(favCity);
    arr.push(newArr[0]);
  };




<div className="details">
        <div className="weather_text">
          <div className="city_tempa">
            <p className="city_name" onChange={(e) => favCity("city", e.target.value)}>
              {weatherSelector.weatherInfo.location.name}
            </p>
            <p className="city_name">, {weatherSelector.weatherInfo.location.country}</p>
            <br />
            <p className="city_temp">{Math.round(weatherSelector.weatherInfo.current.temp_c * 10) / 10}c°</p>
          </div>
          <div className="weather_icon">
            <img className="city_icon" src={weatherSelector.weatherInfo.current.condition.icon} />
            <p className="city_text">{weatherSelector.weatherInfo.current.condition.text}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="fav">
            <button className="fav_btn" onClick={favCity}>
              Add to Favorite
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: `newArr` is a copy of `arr` ... you then push to the END of newArr `newArr.push(favCity);` ... and then push the first element of newArr to arr = completely ignoring the thing you pushed .... remove all reverences to `newArr` ... just `arr.push(favCity)`

Comment: Why you need `newArr`? Anyway, each time you push same one value `arr.push(newArr[0]);`

Comment: by the way, you call favCity function like `favCity("city", e.target.value)` ... but ignore the arguments

Comment: can anyone of you write an example, cause its doesn't seem to work ?

Comment: `const favCity = () => arr.push(weatherSelector.weatherInfo.location.name);`
 that's it, that's the whole function

Comment: by the way, `onChange={(e) => favCity("city", e.target.value)}` suggests something other than plain ol' html

Comment: I tried your solution, same result, the array is still being rewrote

Comment: only the last location is remaining

Comment: forget the onChange, it was an old code, deleted it now

Answer (score 0):

The array you need is the newArr, which contains the new locations. So you just need to assign this newArr to arr.

```
      let arr = [];
    
      const favCity = () => {
        let newArr = [...arr];
        let favCity = weatherSelector.weatherInfo.location.name;
        newArr.push(favCity);
        arr = newArr
      };
```

Comment: same as before, for some reasons the array doesn't keep the previous added city but only keeps the new one

Comment: You'll need to store it somewhere so that data doesn't get lost.

Comment: how should I do that ?

Comment: database or local storage, anything that suits you.

Comment: but the array should be enough no ? why isn't keeping the data ?

Answer (score -1):

Is selecting a new location reloading the page? Because your code doesnt seem to have any problems(as far as we ignore creating a new array for no reason, you can just do arr.push(favCity).

Because that would mean `arr = []` will be inicialized again... if you can post minimal reproducible example (like codepen.io), that would surely clarify a few things

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: no the page isn't reloading, it's react so only the component will reload new stuff.. but it surely look like the arr is inicialized again and again

Comment: I dont have reputation to comment on OP's post